# Display the corresponding tooltip text depending on the circle I did hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 clickable circles with unique ID, and every circle has a different tooltip text. All texts are read from the xml Data Interface.

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'steel_agg_bof_flash_en.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
      });
      function xmlParser(xml) {

          $(xml).find("hotspot").each(function () {
            var position   =  $(this).find('position').text();
            var arr        =  position.split(",");
            var hotspotid  =  $(this).find('hsid').text();
            var title      =  $(this).find('title').text();

            $('#clickAreas').prepend('<div id="'+ hotspotid +'_clickable" class="circle" onclick="changeStyle(id);" style="background: #004593; position: absolute; top: ' + arr[1] + 'px' + '; left: ' + arr[0] + 'px' +'; width: ' + Math.floor(arr[2]/3.28148) + 'px; height: '+ Math.floor(arr[2]/3.28148) + 'px; border-radius: 100%; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.5;"><div class="tooltip"><p style="color: #ffffff;"> ' + title + '</p></div></div>');
          });

        } 

    });
```

and html output look like as shown here - http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/1860/

javascript some css part I added later because I'm trying to do the following:

- when hover over circle tooltip should appear in fade effect, and then when move the mouse outside the circle, tooltip should disappear in fade effect. (I tried to do this with a single circle, but as you can see, when move mouse outside the circle, instead of slowly disappearing, please watch what happens - http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/1851/),
- I can not do it right for one single circle as you can see whats the problem is, especially for more circles to display the corresponding tooltip text depending on the circle I did hover, because now it affects all circles... I dont know, please help me

Comment: try this? https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Here a little help: http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/1865/ javascript should still be updated cause it does now to much work..

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, but you see when you move the mouse, the tooltip text has interruptions when moving, but when I change transition: all 0.5s ease; to transition: opacity 1s ease; there are no interruptions but then fade out is not executed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use CSS transition and use the opacity of the tooltip to achieve the fade effect. Here is a small example on how to do it:

```js
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.clickMapItem .tooltip');

var items = document.querySelectorAll('.clickMapItem').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (e.target == this) {
            var tooltip = e.target.querySelectorAll('.tooltip')[0];
            tooltip.style.opacity = 1;

            if (typeof tooltip !== "undefined") {
                var x = (e.clientX - 10) + 'px',
                    y = (e.clientY - 70) + 'px';

                tooltip.style.top = y;
                tooltip.style.left = x;
            }
        }
    });

    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
        if (e.target == this) {
            var tooltip = e.target.querySelectorAll('.tooltip')[0];
            tooltip.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.clickMapItem {
    background: #004593;
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;*/
    width: 135px;
    height: 135px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5; 
    transition: all 0.5s ease;    
    margin: 30px;
}

.clickMapItem:hover {
    background: #004593;
    opacity: 0.8;

}
.clickMapItem .tooltip {
    /*display:none;*/
    opacity: 0;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: black;
    color: white; 
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   
}
/*.clickMapItem:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
}*/

/*.clickMapItem:hover .tooltip:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  left: 38px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 15px solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent #fff;
}*/
```

```html
<div id="clickMapItem_1" class="clickMapItem">
    <div class="tooltip">
        <p>Tooltip Text</p>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="clickMapItem_2" class="clickMapItem">
    <div class="tooltip">
        <p>One more ytoolytip here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you should not use global window events to do such specific element tasks. Add event listeners directly to elements and avoid doing it globally to the window.

**UPDATE:**

In order to fix the tooltip being displayed even when the mouse hovers on the tooltip itself, you need to do the whole hover handling by using javascript events `mousemove` and `mouseout`. This is because we can't exclude child elements from receiving the `mousemove` event in CSS level, but with javascript we can filter them. Check my updated code to see if it works as you want it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but tooltip also opens when do a hover area where the hidden tooltip, outside the circle. how to fix?

Comment: can you please help me how to fix ?

Comment: Yes, I think you'll need to manage the hover event with javascript. I'll see it and update the answer soon.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. but please if you can use the div structure that I wrote, clickMapItem_1, clickMapItem_2, clickMapItem_3, not just clickMapItem

Comment: `clickMapItem_1`, `clickMapItem_2`, `clickMapItem_3` are just IDs, I have added them to the html elements, but these have nothing to do with the whole tooltip functionality which relies on `clickMapItem` CSS class.

Comment: Again not good, try to hover hidden tooltip area outside the circle, and circle automatically receives Opacity

Comment: This does not occur to me. If I hover outside the circle, the tooltip is hidden. I thought you need to make this by using pure javascript and not using jQuery. It's way easier by using jQuery as you can see.

Comment: ok, I managed to do it this way. http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/1868/    ... but I have to do some fixes, such as to add opacity to the circle on hover and transition on mousemove... Next problem is how to add wave effect around the circle on click . Example http://g.recordit.co/lEhuqjj5tU.gif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128336/discussion-between-mile-mijatovic-and-christos-lytras).

Comment: I recommend working with this person, has a very extensive knowledge. Thanks Christos Lytras

Answer (score 0):

ok, I managed to do it this way

jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/1868/

but I have to do some fixes, such as to add opacity to the circle on hover and transition on mousemove